# Axios put request not updating value

Tags: mongoose, axios

i'm trying to update the values with this method. I've manage to get a 200 status but the data is showing

```
 data: {ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0}
```

This is what i've written using findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, callback). What did i did wrong here?

```
router.put('/sale/:id', function(req, res) {
    let qry = {
        _id: req.params.id
    }
    let doc = {
        date: req.body.date
    }
    let options = {
        returnNewDocument: true
    }
    User.findOneAndUpdate(qry, doc, options, function(err, respRaw) {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        res.status(200).json(respRaw)
    })
})
```

[image]

Comment: Try ```new: true``` instead of ```returnNewDocument: true```. Let me know if it works.

Comment: tried this & changing to findAndUpdate too still it doesn't change the value.

Comment: Upvoted your question. Very interesting issue. I want to know the answer myself.